# Ошибка при импорте модулей node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
(node:19400) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\Nikita\Desktop\node\index.js:1
import chalkPackage from 'chalk'
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:353:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1073:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47**
```

```js
import chalkPackage from 'chalk'

console.log(chalk.blue('nodejs'))
```

Без импорта все отлично работает, пробовал переименовывать, первоначальное название файла main.js, сейчас - index.js. Пару дней назад начал изучать js, поэтому просьба объяснить максимально на пальцах

Comment: Читай что написано в первой строке `set "type": "module" in the package.json`. И всю эту страницу для понимания [packages](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html)

Comment: Или переименуйте `index.js` в `index.mjs`, если не используете `package.json` и просто пишете небольшой скрипт. Использовать современный синтаксис импорта-эспорта можно только в модулях, и нужно дать Node.js подсказку, что файл — это модуль, при помощи расширения или поля в `package.json`.

Comment: Используй либо только конструкцию `const chalkPackage = require("chalk")`, либо добавь в `package.json` `"type": "module"`и используй импорты